# Capturing HTTP & HTTPS urls from nodejs c# python or commandline

Tags: c#, node.js, networking, mono, network-traffic

We are developping a tool to monitor activities from people who are using their **own** pc's to make **exams** on. We need a layer to track network activity, preferably http & https urls for readbility. Lower level is fine too, as long as we can extract the http/https urls from it later on - and possibly opther traffic, such as ftp etc..

The host application is written in NodeJS/Electron, but we could interface with command line tools if needed, or via edge.js.

The users **know** they're being tracked as they sign a contract before starting the exams / assignments. But we do need a cross platform solution on both linux, mac and windows (different tools per platform are an option too) to get that network traffic without being too technical for our users. Our tool should instantiate the process and shut it down as well. So no fiddling around with users having to configure too much inside interfaces or via the command line. If we can do it for them without ADMIN/Sudo preferably, it's a plus.

Are there any options for such a use case?

Comment: Possibly pcap is what you looking for (https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/) with this you can write a simple network sniffer.

Comment: @C1sc0 and then use libpcap on linux and mac I presume?

Comment: As i know yes you can use also on linux or on unix.